# Kute.js integration on Astro

Tags: javascript, astrojs

How to integrate kute js on Astro?
I'm a beginner and want to learn animation with the help of JavaScript.

I tried CDN and so that I can do animation in cool Astro with third part JS integration.
Help me, I'm beginner in Astro and coding,
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Intro

using Kute.js or any other library with Astro is not much different than using vanilla javascript and npm modules

## Steps

1. first add Kute js to your project with `npm install kute.js` or `pnpm install kute.js`
2. add the SVG directly in your .astro page where Layout is optional

```js
---
---
<Layout title="Welcome to Astro.">
        <p>
            <button id="start"">Start</button>
        </p>
        <svg id="morph-example" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
            <path id="rectangle" class="bg-red" d="M38.01,5.653h526.531c17.905,0,32.422,14.516,32.422,32.422v526.531 c0,17.905-14.517,32.422-32.422,32.422H38.01c-17.906,0-32.422-14.517-32.422-32.422V38.075C5.588,20.169,20.104,5.653,38.01,5.653z"/>
            <path id="star" style="visibility:hidden" d="M301.113,12.011l99.25,179.996l201.864,38.778L461.706,380.808 l25.508,203.958l-186.101-87.287L115.01,584.766l25.507-203.958L0,230.785l201.86-38.778L301.113,12.011"/>
        </svg>
</Layout>
```

3. add a script tag in your .astro where you simply import KUTE and use it

```js
<script>
    import KUTE from 'kute.js'
    const start = document.getElementById('start')
    start.onclick = ()=>{
        var tween = KUTE.to('#rectangle', { path: '#star' }).start();
    }
</script>
```

## Example

Repo

here a ready demo example of Kute.js Morph used with Astro https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples#52_kutejs-morph

Live demo

https://astro-kutejs-morph.netlify.app/